# Regular expression to validate file name against blank spaces

Tags: javascript

the below java script regular expression is to validate a file name for special characters.

```
fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp("[~#%&*{}<>;?/+|\"]");
```

How can I include white space also in this regexp? I want to validate my attachment for blank spaces.

Thanks,
Sijo

Comment: @Jan, its not fixed by adding a space in the regexp. also /s not seems to be working with IE 7.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a space in your regular expression.

```
fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp("[~#%&*{}<>;?/+|\" ]");
```

Comment: I think you meant to put that space inside the brackets, not outside.

Comment: I would use `\s` to catch *any type of whitespace

Comment: This code works perfect in chrome and firefox. But its not working with IE 7

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function PreSaveAction() 
{ 
var attachment; 
var filename=""; 
var fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp('\\s', 'g'); 
try { 
attachment = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].firstChild; 
filename = attachment.data; 
} 
catch (e) { 
} 
if (fileNameSpecialCharacters.test(filename)) { 
alert("Please remove the special characters and white spaces from file attachment name.");
return false; 
} 
else { 
return true; 
} 
} </script>